# Conjure-Up Landscape failure

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas, openstack-autopilot

I am current following [this guide](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/autopilot) to test out Ubuntu's Autopilot setup.

The section of deploying Landscape is not working on my end, and am wondering if anyone can provide assistance.

I have a working MaaS setup that can commission, and deploy without any issues.  However when I try to conjure-up the landscape on another machine I am getting errors within the JuJu log files.

```
2017-06-20 12:26:40 ERROR juju.state allwatcher.go:399 getting a public address for unit "landscape-server/0" failed: "no public address(es)"
2017-06-20 12:26:40 ERROR juju.state allwatcher.go:403 getting a private address for unit "landscape-server/0" failed: "no private address(es)"
2017-06-20 12:26:40 ERROR juju.state allwatcher.go:399 getting a public address for unit "rabbitmq-server/0" failed: "no public address(es)"
2017-06-20 12:26:40 ERROR juju.state allwatcher.go:403 getting a private address for unit "rabbitmq-server/0" failed: "no private address(es)"
```

Not able to find anything regarding this on the Google. [Here](https://pastebin.com/WZKHVDFK) is the full debug log for JuJu.

Answer (score 0):

The conjure-up screen was waiting on MaaS to release another host to use in this situation.  One for the JuJu controller, and one for the Landscape system. So it just sat waiting for a host to be ready without canceling.  User error, and we can close this out.